# Scheduled job not sending emails

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, email

I believe that dbMail is properly set up, I can send an email to myself using it.
But I have a scheduleded job which looks like;

```
DECLARE @Forename VARCHAR(50) 
DECLARE @EmailAddress VARCHAR(50)
DECLARE @subject VARCHAR(500)
DECLARE @emailsubject VARCHAR(500)
Declare @bodypre as  varchar(5000)
DECLARE @body VARCHAR(5000)
declare @recipients VARCHAR(5000)
Declare @emailStop  as int
declare @replaceApproverName as varchar(20)
declare @link as varchar(100)
declare @replaceNextLine as varchar(20)
declare @profile_name as varchar(50)
declare @bodypost as varchar(5000)
declare @footerMessage as varchar(1000)
set @replaceApproverName ='$Approver'
set @replaceNextLine ='$NextLine'
set @link ='$Link'
DECLARE @NewLineChar AS CHAR(1) = CHAR(13) 

select @emailsubject=EmailMessageSubject,
@bodypre = EmailMessageBody,
@emailStop = EmailStop_Flag
from STAS.dbo.MC_STAS_EmailMessage where TimeSheetStatusID = 2 

SET @bodypre =Replace(@bodypre ,@link, 'http://liveweb.website.com/stas');
select @footerMessage =EmailMessageBody  from STAS.dbo.MC_STAS_EmailMessage where MessageType='Footer'
SET @bodypre += @footerMessage;
SET @bodypre =Replace(@bodypre ,@replaceNextLine, @NewLineChar) ; 
DECLARE emailCursor CURSOR  FOR 
SELECT  distinct EmailAddress,Forename  from [STAS].[dbo].[NotifictationEmailID_View] vw
OPEN emailCursor FETCH NEXT FROM 
emailCursor INTO @EmailAddress,@Forename WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 
BEGIN       
if(@emailStop = 1)
set @EmailAddress = 'xxx.xxxx@xxxxx.co.uk'
set @bodypost  = Replace(@bodypre,@replaceApproverName,@Forename) 
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail 
@profile_name='STAS Alert',                         
                    @recipients =@EmailAddress,   
                    @subject=@emailsubject,                                 
                    @body =@bodypost;

FETCH NEXT FROM emailCursor INTO @EmailAddress,@Forename END 
CLOSE emailCursor 
DEALLOCATE emailCursor
```

When I look at the Database mail error log I see this;

```
The mail could not be sent to the recipients because of the mail server failure. (Sending Mail using Account 1 (2013-09-04T14:03:48). Exception Message: Cannot send mails to mail server. (The operation has timed out.).
Sending Mail using Account 1 . Exception Message: Cannot send mails to mail server. (Failure sending mail.).
```

Yet the profile 'STAS Alert' is set up and I can send an email using it to myself.
So why is this happening and what should I do to fix it?

Comment: Did you view this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10626926/sending-email-through-sql-server-failed

Comment: Try to run this script in SSMS query window without Agent. Also, it's good practice to receive and analyze return value from execution of `sp_send_dbmail`.

Answer (score 2):

Did you check out SQL Server Agent Properties/alert system ?
Mail profile should be enabled and your mail profile should be chosen correctly.

Comment: The database mail is set up and I tested it by sending an email to myself using msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail

Comment: I issued this problem once, in Sql Server Agent 2008 there is a problem . Go to Sql Server Agent properties , Alert system , check out youe email profile. there is a problem with Sql Server Agent,restart Sql Server Agent from configuration manager ,if it does not word the problem is not solving, do as i do, upgrade to Sql Server 2012 ,Problem will solve.

Comment: I thought you were onto something when I found that the mail profile had not been enabled. But enabling that did not fix the problem, and upgrading to SQL Server 2012 is not a decision I can make.

Comment: Did you restart the SQL Agent service after enabling the mail profile in the SQL Server Agent properties?  The setting does not take effect until this is done.