# Cannot send database Mail using sql server 2008 r2 Data Center Edition

Tags: sql-server, database, smtp

I have configured different ways and tried to send test email , didn't work.
Error: The mail could not be sent to the recipients because of the mail server failure. (Sending Mail using Account 5 (2018-01-22T14:28:24). Exception Message: Could not connect to mail server.
 (A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond 74.125.24.108:587). )

Configured the database Mail as blow. 
[image]

I have tried possible changes but still getting failed. 
1.Verified all usernames and passwords
2.Checked with different ports 465 ,587 and default 25
3.pinged  SMTP.gmail.com its working
4.Control antivirus and firewall settings

I have refereed 
[Sending Email through SQL Server FAILED](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10626926/sending-email-through-sql-server-failed)

any other ways ?

Answer (score 0):

Please check your settings on GMail. You need to switch on the 'Allow Less Secure Apps' setting so that it will allow third party apps such as SQL Server to access the GMail servers.