# database mail configuration

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Configuring database mail is successful but testing fails.

I ran `SELECT * FROM sysmail_log` and found following

> The mail could not be sent to the recipients because of the mail server failure. (Sending Mail using Account 2 (2017-08-02T12:07:02). Exception Message: Could not connect to mail server. (No such host is known).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sending Email through SQL Server FAILED](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10626926/sending-email-through-sql-server-failed)