# SQL Server 2014 DB Mail Not Sending

Tags: sql-server

I'm on SQL Server 2014 and having a blast... my DB Mail isn't sending and I'm running out of places to look. I double checked the SQL account permissions to the DBmail executable - it has read and execute. I tried another mail account and profile with the same unsent issues.

I'm running below queries as described here

**Step # 1**

Checking rights of dbowner

[image]

**Setup # 2**

```
USE MASTER
GO

SP_CONFIGURE 'show advanced options', 1
RECONFIGURE WITH OVERRIDE
GO

SP_CONFIGURE 'Database Mail XPs', 1
RECONFIGURE WITH OVERRIDE
GO

SP_CONFIGURE 'show advanced options', 0
RECONFIGURE WITH OVERRIDE
GO
```

and above query successfully run without any error's

[image]

**Step # 3**

Configure Database Mail by using below query

```
EXECUTE msdb.dbo.sysmail_add_profile_sp  
    @profile_name = 'P2PEmailNotifications',  
    @description = 'Profile used for sending outgoing notifications using Gmail.' ;  
GO

EXECUTE msdb.dbo.sysmail_add_principalprofile_sp  
    @profile_name = 'P2PEmailNotifications',  
    @principal_name = 'public',  
    @is_default = 1 ;
GO

EXECUTE msdb.dbo.sysmail_add_account_sp  
    @account_name = 'MyGmail',  
    @description = 'Mail account for sending outgoing notifications.',  
    @email_address = 'MyGmailSMTPEMAIL@gmail.com',  
    @display_name = 'no-reply@ubl.com.pk',  
    @mailserver_name = 'smtp.gmail.com',
    @port = 555,
    @enable_ssl = 1,
    @username = 'MyGmailSMTPEMAIL@gmail.com',
    @password = 'xxxxxxx' ;  
GO

EXECUTE msdb.dbo.sysmail_add_profileaccount_sp  
    @profile_name = 'P2PEmailNotifications',  
    @account_name = 'MyGmail',  
    @sequence_number =1 ;  
GO
```

**Step # 4**

Now, trying to execute dbmail by using below query:

```
EXEC [msdb].[dbo].[sp_send_dbmail] 
     @profile_name = 'P2PEmailNotifications', 
     @recipients = 'xxx.xxx.xxx@outlook.com', 
     @subject = @Subject2,
     @body = @Body2,
     @body_format = 'HTML'
```

**Output**

Now, there are no errors anywhere that I can find in my result window.

[image]

**Step # 5**

So, I got these queries to check if there is any error while sending the dbmail  and run it:

```
SELECT * 
FROM msdb..sysmail_event_log 
ORDER BY log_id DESC
```

[image]

This is the error which is in the description column:

> The mail could not be sent to the recipients because of the mail server failure. (Sending Mail using Account 9 (2019-04-11T00:21:06). Exception Message: Could not connect to mail server. (A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond 64.233.167.109:555).
>   )

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.sysmail_sentitems
```

[image]

After seeing the error I have repeated the step 3 by changing the different gmail email and by changing the port 555 to 587 after that I have received below error in the description column

[image]

Exception information

> Exception Type: Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlIMail.Server.Common.BaseException
>
> Message: Could not retrieve item from the queue. Reason: the list of accounts which could send this mail is empty (probably due to the use of invalid profile).
>
> Data: System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal
>   TargetSite: Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlIMail.Server.Controller.ICommand CreateSendMailCommand(Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlIMail.Server.DataAccess.DBSession)
>   HelpLink: NULL
>   Source: DatabaseMailEngine

StackTrace Information

> at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlIMail.Server.Controller.CommandFactory.CreateSendMailCommand(DBSession dbSession)
>   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlIMail.Server.Controller.CommandRunner.Run(DBSession db)
>      at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlIMail.IMailProcess.ThreadCallBack.MailOperation(Object obj)

**Conclusion**

I've got a queue of items with sent status "failed". As I describe my problem briefly. So, I need some answers from you developers that what I'm doing wrong in my above steps is I'm missing something or Is this a known issue with SQL Server 2014 that I haven't in my searches? Any other possible steps to get this mail sent?

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10626926/sending-email-through-sql-server-failed