# Unable to send an email from SQL Query in SQL Server 2012/2014/2016

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2016

I configured database Mail from the wizard and able to get email alerts.

[image]

When I'm writing the following query:

```
DECLARE @IsFileExists INT   
EXEC Master.dbo.xp_fileexist 'g:\abc.bak', @IsFileExists OUT  

BEGIN  
    IF @IsFileExists = 1  
    BEGIN  
        PRINT 'File Exists in the G:\ location'  
    END  
    ELSE  
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @htmlbody VARCHAR(4000)

        EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
                  @profile_name = 'EMAIL',
                  @recipients = 'ylx@xly.com',
                  @subject = 'Database Mail Test'
        PRINT 'File Does not Exist in the G:\ location'
    END --IF
END
```

I'm not receiving any email alert:

Here is the output:

> (1 row affected)
>   Mail (Id: 1065) queued.
>   File Does not Exist in the g:\ location

[image]

Description: The mail could not be sent to the recipients because of the mail server failure. (Sending Mail using Account 1 (2019-12-11T19:00:19). Exception Message: Cannot send mails to mail server. (Failure sending mail.).  )

All SQL services are running, executed the script as a sysadmin user. 
Can someone please advise:

Comment: Please post the exception message, it is not visible or readable in your screenshot.

Comment: smtp.xly.com with anonymous authentication? So you've tested that independently and you know it works?

Comment: I seriously doubt any email server will allow anon use. And pick an engine - you cannot - at this point - be using multiple versions. It doesn't help that the versions you tag do not match the versions you put in topic.

Comment: @robbpriestley: YES., Tried with aanonymous authentication. tested that independently and it works.but  not when I execute it in query.

Comment: So that's your problem? You can't send mail through that SMTP server in the first place? Your screenshot above clearly shows you are using Anonymous Authentication.

Comment: @robbpriestley: I can send an email through the SMTP server. The issue comes when I use it in a query.

Comment: Oh, I see. Well it does say "File Does not Exist in the g:\ location" because your "query" (it's a script, actually) always does that via PRINT statement. You do know that, right?

Comment: @robbpriestley: YES. . all I need is to get an email ...

Answer (score 1):

> **That message came from the SMTP server, not DBMail.**
>
> This is not a DBMail issue. The message indicates the recipient email
>   address does not exist.  Check your email address.

As stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10626926/sending-email-through-sql-server-failed)

> Some suggested troubleshooting steps:
>
> 1. Try to send a message through the same SMTP server, using the same machine as SQL Server, using a client mail program like Outlook. You
>      may get a more meaningful error message.
> 2. The port may be blocked. Try sending mail to any other SMTP server using port 587.
> 3. Try changing to port 465.
> 4. Try unchecking the "requires a secure connection" bit in your profile.
> 5. Try using an SMTP server inside your network to relay to GMail. This might be easier to set up and get running. You'll need to install
>      IIS and the SMTP components if you don't have a local SMTP server
>      available to handle the relay.
> 6. Review http://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=13287

If you are using GMAIL then please take care of one extra step below:

- After you configure the email in the Database Mail, Please log in your gmail account and go to

  https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps

Turn on your less secure app to use your account, that's how the database mail can access your gmail SMTP account.

Try sending test mail using following code:

```
    USE msdb
    GO
    EXEC sp_send_dbmail @profile_name='XXX', -- Your profile name
    @recipients='abc@yahoo.com', -- Recipient's email address
    @subject='Test message',
    @body='This is the body of the test message.'
```

At last, try to run following query to see whether its sent or not

```
    SELECT * FROM sysmail_log
```

Comment: I was also thinking maybe since @aditya y reports being able to send mail through the server, perhaps that is only locally where the local machine is whitelisted but then the MSSQL machine is not. Just a guess, but it is so unusual that a mail server would allow anonymous access. That makes me think maybe there is some other mechanism for security.